# Lumen Salesforce Application

Tags: integration, webservices, appexchange, connected-apps, data-import

Can anyone briefly explain these Lumen Salesforce Application/Lumen Software concepts?

1. Objective
2. Data Model
3. Editions

Is there a free trial version of Lumen Salesforce Application/Lumen Software available? If yes where can I find it? How can I enable Lumen Salesforce Application in my Developer Org?